# error: assignement to expression with array type

Tags: c, if

Estou tentando compilar o código abaixo para uma lista de exercicios do meu curso curso de introdução a programação porem o codeblocks apresanta o erro citado no titulo quando tento compilar o código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float peso,altura,imc;
    char nome[40],categoria[40];

    printf("Qual o nome da pessoa? ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nome);

    printf("\nQual a altura dessa pessoa em metros? ");
    scanf("%f",&altura);

    printf("\nQual o peso dessa pessoa em kilos? ");
    scanf("%f",&peso);

    imc=peso/(altura*altura);

    if(imc<18.5){
        categoria='abaixo do peso';
    }

    if((18.5<=imc)&&(imc<25)){
        categoria='peso normal';
    }

    if((25<=imc)&&(imc<30)){
        categoria='acima do peso';
    }

    if(imc>=30){
        categoria='obesidade';
    }

    printf("\n%s esta com indice de massa corporal %f(%s)", nome, imc, categoria);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não sei se resolve o problema, mas como estudo, dá uma lida [nesse link](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/488628-gets-e-fflushstdin/)

Answer (score 2):

O problema está aqui:

```
categoria='abaixo do peso';
```

Para começar tem de ser aspas duplas `"` em vez de aspas simples `'`, e também não pode ser atribuído diretamente como está a fazer.

Para copiar o texto para o array de `char` que tem, deve utilizar a função [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

```
strcpy(categoria, "abaixo do peso");
//       ^--- destino      ^--- texto a copiar
```

Uma vez que esta função faz parte da biblioteca de strings é importante que a importe no topo:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Deve aplicar o `strcpy` às restantes partes do código que tinham o mesmo problema.

---

Como recomendação para o futuro, evite a todo o custo utilizar a função `gets`, pois ela não é segura.